# Index on a Date column - use Between/And or Greater/Less

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I was asked this question at an interview. AdventurWorks2012.Sales.CreditCard table. First, I created a non-clustered index on ModifiedDate column to simulate the interview question. I need to find records for, let's say July, 2007

```
SELECT cc.CreditCardID, cc.ModifiedDate
FROM sales.CreditCard cc
WHERE cc.ModifiedDate >= '07/01/2007' OR cc.ModifiedDate < '08/01/2007'
------------
SELECT cc.CreditCardID, cc.ModifiedDate
FROM sales.CreditCard cc
WHERE cc.ModifiedDate BETWEEN '07/01/2007' AND  '07/31/2007'
------------
SELECT cc.CreditCardID,  cc.ModifiedDate
FROM sales.CreditCard cc
WHERE Year(cc.ModifiedDate) = 2007 AND month(cc.ModifiedDate) = 7
```

Here are the execution plans. 1) I don't get it why Between is the fastest query and the only one using NCIndex, whereas I was told standard SQL(first query) would be the fastest. 2) They say, avoid using functions in where clause, but, it is showing the same result with the first query where I don't use a function.

[image]

Comment: The first two aren't the same semantically - are you sure you mean `OR` in the first?

Comment: Note that your first question will give all rows because you have an or.

Comment: My bad, sorry, question closed. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments. The first statments where clause is incorrectly using OR instead of AND and will make the statement return all rows which will be slower than a subset of the rows.

Comment: well, my answer basically answers both his questions.